# One time data binding in repeaters

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, protractor, angularjs-ng-repeat

Several of the repeaters used in our application use the [one-time data binding expression syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ::values" class="grid-column-filter-item ng-scope">  
</div>
```

Which we currently locate with the [`by.repeater()` locator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater):

```
element.all(by.repeater("item in ::values"));
```

Our concern is that the `::` part is not relevant and is a technical implementation detail that should not be a part of the locator. Ideally, we are looking for:

```
element.all(by.repeater("item in values"));
```

But, according to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2434), both the `by.repeater()` and the `by.exactRepeater()` don't remove the one-time data bindings, but do remove other repeater syntax parts like `track by` or `as`.

Do we have any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing this?

```
$$('[ng-repeat^="item in"]')
```

Which returns all elements with `ng-repeat` attribute starting with "item in". Or to make the exact match, you can do:

```
$$('[ng-repeat^="item in"][ng-repeat$="values"]')
```